# VirtualBox: Network Sharing

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-shares

I'm trying to set up normal network sharing between my virtualbox host and guest. When I use NAT networking, I can get internet on my guest, but I heard network sharing is not possible. I heard to do network sharing you need to use a Host-Only network and Bridged Network, but I when I switch to Host-Only I have no more internet access, and I heard Bridged networks sometimes cause issues with your router. Is there a way to get the best of both worlds, internet access and network sharing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this trick in my environment. Your VirtualBox Guest will uses two interfaces . One interface becomes `NAT` and the other one becomes `Host-Only`. Don't forget to add default route to `NAT` interface.